# Using JavaScript to load haarcascasdes file always return false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, opencv

I'm doing my first web application with opencv, this [OpenCV Face Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d99/tutorial_js_face_detection.html) tutorial guide me to load `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` then detect face in a photo, the sample code below:

```
let faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
faceCascade.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'); //<--return false
```

[My haarcascades file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM722.png)

Because of the failure loading, I cannot use `detectMultiScale` function, the error log is :

`Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file /build/master-contrib_docs-lin64/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1698`

Does my haarcascade file put in a wrong place? or parameter in `load()` is wrong?

Comment: try to open `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` from yours browser url to see if its open - or have permissions or other issues

Comment: @Aristos Do you mean `open in browser` to open `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xm` ?

Comment: type on your browser `http://www.example.com/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xm` and see if opens or you have errors

Comment: @Aristos sorry for late reply, `http://localhost:port/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` can be opened successfully, but console has error says `contentInject.js:5273 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of undefined`

Comment: so this is the real error - look for this on google and look inside the js file to see what can not be read

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to make the file accessible to cv by reading it into the opencv file system. To do this, you need to use an XMLHttpRequest() to get the XML file using its URL and then call the cv.CascadeClassifier as follows:

```
const xml_model_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml';
const xml_path = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
let faceCascade = null;

function createFileFromUrl(path, url, callback) {
// path: string to access loaded file trough cv
// url: path of the actual file on your FS
// callback: what to do when file is loaded

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function(ev) {
      request = this;
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
          if (request.status === 200) {
              let data = new Uint8Array(request.response);
              cv.FS_createDataFile('/', path, data, true, false, false);
              callback();
          } else {
              console.error('Failed to load ' + url + ' status: ' + request.status);
          }
      }
  };
  request.send();
}
function createCascade() {
  faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier(xml_path);
}
createFileFromUrl(xml_path, xml_model_url,createCascade);
```